# Is there a list of default fields and default widgets for drupal 7

Tags: entities

Where can I a list of available (in the core) fields and widgets and their names so I can reference them when adding fields to my own node-type definitions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a list of all field definitions use [`field_info_fields()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.info.inc/function/field_info_fields/7)

> Returns all field definitions.
>
> Use of this function should be avoided when possible, since it loads and statically caches a potentially large array of information. Use field_info_field_map() instead.

You can ignore the second paragraph of that as `field_info_field_map()` hasn't actually been included in a Drupal release yet.

For widgets use [`field_info_widget_types()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.info.inc/function/field_info_widget_types/7)

> Returns information about field widgets from hook_field_widget_info().

Comment: Thank you - that also gave further insight into how to work with drupal APIs. ( Also , in fact I was interested in field-types, which I got through field_info_field_types() )

Comment: Ah gotcha :) You might be interested in the [field.info.inc file](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.info.inc/7) as a whole if you haven't already come across it